# How can I cancel DynamoDB Restore

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, restore

I started restore for DynamoDB table from backup. The table has millions of records and it is taking a long time. I would like to cancel the Restore and I cannot find the option from AWS Console. I tried to delete the table using aws cli and I am greeted with resource is being used error message. Is there a way to cancel restore? Thank you!

Comment: you may would like to submit feature request to aws. login to aws account and go to support center.